# mixing up Backbone and Parse

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm migrating a web app to parse.com. It is written in Backbone. Right now, I have only 1 collection out of 5 that is fetched from parse, and I'm having trouble integrating it into the web app.

my question is simple: can I combine parse and backbone models and views? are the compatible. For example, can I have a Parse collection and pass it to a Backbone View?

Comment: It was designed to be backbone compatible, but has not been kept up to date with new backbone features.. give it a shot.

Comment: BB works very well w/ parse.. Try using the sample todo app https://github.com/priley86/parse-marionette-todo  marionette may be more framewrk than needed but its very good if u have the time to inspect